# How can I get the last month's data to display it for each day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns (ID, StartWork) and in each table they are called differently. I need to calculate the amount of work done for each day during the last month.

With this request, I was only able to get the total amount of data

```
SELECT
((SELECT COUNT(Incidents.Id) FROM Incidents WHERE Created >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
+ (SELECT COUNT(ApprovedWorks.Id) FROM ApprovedWorks WHERE WorkStarted >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
+ (SELECT COUNT(dbo.Demos.Id) FROM dbo.Demos WHERE [Start] >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
+ (SELECT COUNT(AcceptanceTests.Id) FROM AcceptanceTests WHERE [Start] >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
+ (SELECT COUNT(dbo.Notifications.Id) FROM dbo.Notifications WHERE [Start] >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())))
```

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: well geee golly it doesnt look like youve really explained what youre trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create a Calendar table and base your query off of it. This ensures no day gaps in your output. Then normalize the query you provided above to produce a uniform output. Join the output of your table against the calendar and group by calendar day and aggregate.

NOTE : I am not able to verify this will compile without schema, but it should.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

;WITH OrderedDays as 
( 
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM OrderedDays WHERE DATEADD (DAY, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
),
Calendar AS
(
    SELECT
        DayIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CalendarDate),
        CalendarDate,
        CalenderDayOfMonth = DATEPART(DAY, CalendarDate),
        CalenderMonthOfYear = DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate),
        CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate),
        CalenderWeekOfYear = DATEPART(WEEK, CalendarDate),
        CalenderQuarterOfYear = DATEPART(QUARTER, CalendarDate),
        CalenderDayOfYear =  DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, CalendarDate),
        CalenderDayOfWeek =  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CalendarDate),
        CalenderWeekday =  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CalendarDate)   
    FROM
        OrderedDays                 
)
, Data AS
(
    (SELECT TableID=1, Incidents.Id, EventDate=Created FROM Incidents WHERE Created >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=2, ApprovedWorks.Id, EventDate=WorkStarted FROM ApprovedWorks WHERE WorkStarted >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=3, dbo.Demos.Id EventDate=[Start] FROM dbo.Demos WHERE [Start] >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=4, AcceptanceTests.Id, EventDate=[Start] FROM AcceptanceTests WHERE [Start] >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=5, dbo.Notifications.Id, EventDate=[Start] FROM dbo.Notifications WHERE [Start] >= @StartDate)
)

SELECT 
    EventType = TableID,
    EventCount = COUNT(ID),
    C.CalendarDay
FROM 
    Calendar C
    INNER JOIN Data D ON D.EventDate = C.CalendarDate
GROUP BY
    EventType,C.CalendarDay
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

If you dont care about listing days with no activity then there is no need for a calendar table, simply combine then group.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) 
;
WITH Data AS
(
    (SELECT TableID=1, Incidents.Id, EventDate=Created FROM Incidents WHERE Created >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=2, ApprovedWorks.Id, EventDate=WorkStarted FROM ApprovedWorks WHERE WorkStarted >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=3, dbo.Demos.Id EventDate=[Start] FROM dbo.Demos WHERE [Start] >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=4, AcceptanceTests.Id, EventDate=[Start] FROM AcceptanceTests WHERE [Start] >= @StartDate)
    UNION
    (SELECT TableID=5, dbo.Notifications.Id, EventDate=[Start] FROM dbo.Notifications WHERE [Start] >= @StartDate)
)

SELECT 
    EventType = TableID,
    EventCount = COUNT(ID),
    EventDate
FROM 
    Data 
GROUP BY
    EventType,
    EventDate
```

Comment: I can do it without creating a table, just a query?

Comment: Yes but it will be difficult to ensure no gaps.

Comment: I added a less verbose query that can allows gaps.